# Wrap all nodes in a DocumentFragment with a DIV

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

Given a simple DocumentFragment:

```
html = "<h1>Three's Company</h1><p>A love triangle.</p>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse html
```

Is there an elegant way to wrap everything the DocumentFragment holds with a DIV? Please note that I have to do this inside a method which is supposed to return a DocumentFragment instance `doc` which has been parsed elsewhere. I'd like `doc.to_html` to look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper"><h1>Three's Company</h1><p>A love triangle.</p></div>
```

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Forgot to mention: The method I'm working on is supposed to return a DocumentFragment instance, I'll precise this in the question above. Simply wrapping with strings doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found :

```
require 'nokogiri'

string = "<h1>Three's Company</h1><p>A love triangle.</p>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse "<div class='foo'>"
doc.at(".//div").inner_html = string 
puts doc.to_html
```

output:

```
<div class="foo">
  <h1>Three's Company</h1>
  <p>A love triangle.</p>
</div>
```